# Java regex for matching various types of section headers

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex (for use in Java) with which to match potential section headings. The section headings can be either roman numerals (up to 39) or things like "A.3. 10", "3.4", "4", "34 .A", etc. But it seems to be matching just either roman numerals or just the other part, even though I'm using alternation in the regex. I'm testing via https://regexr.com/.

This is my regex:

```
(\b(?:(?:X{0,3}(?:I[V|X]|V?I{0,3}))|(?:(?:[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z])(?:\s?\.\s?(?:[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z])){0,2}))\b)
```

Each part (roman numeral vs. letter+digit) seems to be behaving correctly by itself:

```
roman numeral:
(\bX{0,3}(?:I[V|X]|V?I{0,3})\b)

letter+digit:
(\b(?:[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z])(?:\s?\.\s?(?:[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z])){0,2}\b)
```

Here are some test cases that should match:

```
Section A.3
Section A . 34
Section 3 . A
Section 1.2.5.6
Section 1.2.5
Section 1.2. 5
Section 1 . 2 . 5
Section III
Section  XVI
Section IX
Section 3.B
Section 35.C
Section A.B.34
Section 3
Section 34
Section C
Section 34.35
Section A.3.C
Section 3.A.5
```

Here are some that should not pass:

```
A common phrase is this though..
Section AB.34
Section AB.5
Section CD
Section 345
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: @user I do care about valid roman numerals (up to number 39, meaning don't need to worry about L, D, C, or M). I fixed my question to include the correct example (`Section III` instead of `Section IIII`).

Comment: A crazy remix - see [here](https://regex101.com/r/Wma1wx/1)

Comment: What about `A.B.34`, should it pass? Also, you can drop the `|` in `[V|X]`

Comment: @ctwheels yes, that should pass. I've added few more positive and negative test examples to question now.

Comment: @user So I don't get it, is the regexr.com site broken or is the regex101.com site broken? Or is it because they're using different languages, and regex behaves differently for different languages? I need it to work for Java.

Comment: @user1145925 multiple regex engines - different for each language, although some use the same engine. Also, what about `A.5.B` and `4.C.4`

Comment: @ctwheels I updated question again to include things like `A.5.B` or `4.C.4` as positive examples. Good point about dropping the `|` in `[V|X]`.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Wma1wx/2. I suspect you want to only match at the end of the string.

Comment: Updating @WiktorStribiżew's first regex: https://regex101.com/r/Wma1wx/3 - you can likely also replace `(?!\S)` with `$` - not sure if more text can follow the section header on the same line

Comment: Did anything finally work for you? Did you come up with the final set of requirements for the pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yup, I've posted my answer below. My requirements ended up changing a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My requirements ended up a bit different than the details in the original question. Below are the 2 regexes I ended up using for my 2 different use cases, as well as the test examples they are passing:

1) https://regex101.com/r/D9sQGz/2

```
(\b(?<!\w)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z])(?:\s?\.\s?(?:[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z])){0,2}\b(?<=\w))
```

2) https://regex101.com/r/v0NjW6/2

```
(\b(?<!\w)X{0,3}(?:I[VX]|V?I{0,3})\b(?<=\w)(?:\s?\.\s?(?:[0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z])){0,2}\b(?<=\w))
```

Answer (score -1):

The pattern for letter+digit matches also two of the bad cases:

```
Section AB.34 -->
Section AB.<word boundary>34<word boundary>
```

Try to get the individual regexes correct an then test again!

There should be no problem in combining two regexes like this (as done in your code):

```
(?:(?:regex1)|(?:regex2))
```

Also consider to use two regexes and do the or operation in Java code. This is simpler to understand for someone who has to read your code later.